# Phaser Javascript game, this keyword and game states

Tags: javascript

I have just started using Phaser to create Javascript games and have questions regarding the 'this' keyword.

- Does **this** refer to the current state (rainState)?
- I assume **this.emitter = this.game.add.emitter(100, 0, 400);** creates an emitter property on the rainState object that stores an emitter object ?
- Is game a property of state? why do write  **this.game.add.emitter**  as opposed to **this.add emitter**

//-------------------------------------------------

```
     var Smash = Smash || {};

    Smash.rainState = {
        create: function() {
            this.emitter = this.game.add.emitter(this.game.world.centerX, 0, 400);

            this.emitter.width = this.game.world.width;
            this.emitter.angle = 30;
            this.emitter.makeParticles('particle');

            this.player = new Smash.Player(this.game, 100, 300, 'player');

            this.intro0();       
        },

        intro0: function() {
          this.player.animations.play("run", 9, true);
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does this refer to the current state (rainState)?

The answer is it depends how it is called.

If it's called as a method of the `rainState` object, the context (`this`) will be set to the `rainState` object:

```
Smash.rainState.create();
```

Using `call`, `apply`, or `bind` you can pass in whatever scope you want as an argument:

```
Smash.rainState.create.call(foo); //immediately invoked
Smash.rainState.create.apply(foo); //immediately invoked
var bar = Smash.rainState.create.bind(foo); //reference to a newly created bound function
```

> I assume this.emitter = this.game.add.emitter(100, 0, 400); creates an emitter property on the rainState objects that stores an emitter object ?

Yes when you assign a value to `this.emitter` it is added as a property of the object `rainState`.

```
Smash.rainState = {
    create: function() {
        console.log(Smash.rainState.emitter); //undefined
        this.emitter = this.game.add.emitter(this.game.world.centerX, 0, 400);
        console.log(Smash.rainState.emitter); //[object Object]
    },      
};
```

> Is game a property of state? why do write this.game.add.emitter as opposed to this.add emitter

Based on the code you've provided, it doesn't look like `game` is a method or property of `rainState`. Furthermore, `this.add` is not a built-in function of the `object` type.  Unless `game` has been added as a property of `rainState` somewhere else, you'll need to refer to it in another way.

Globally:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game();

var Smash = Smash || {};

Smash.rainState = {
    create: function() {
         this.emitter = game.add.emitter(this.game.world.centerX, 0, 400);
```

As a parameter passed in from a place where `game` exists in context:

```
Smash.rainState = {
    create: function(game) {
         this.emitter = game.add.emitter(this.game.world.centerX, 0, 400);
    }
}

//a context where game is a property
{
    this.game = new Phaser.Game();   

    Smash.rainState.create(this.game);
}
```

Phaser has some specific settings around how you refer to the `game` instantiation of the `Phaser.Game` class in different contexts:

> "Via": If a class has an entry in the via column it means you can quickly access it through a local reference. I.e. you can control the camera via this.camera from any state, or game.camera if game has been globally defined.

This means if you initialized your `game` instance in the global scope (outside of any `{}`) then you should be able to call it globally.  Look for something like this in your code and make sure it's not inside another function or object:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });
```

Comment: hi stephen, thanks, this is a great answer. The game object is created with the code...... var Smash = Smash || {}; ...... Smash.game = new Phaser.Game(640, 480, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser');.. However this state is created in a diffferent file -  game.js (the entry point of the game) – stckpete 8 mins ago

Comment: It looks like the Phaser.State class has `game` as a property: [Phaser.State](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.State.html).  If you are passing `Smash.rainState` into a function that creates an instance of the Phaser.State class then your `rainState` properties will be combined with the Phaser.State properties and `this.game` should work.